# using cases in \Aboxed{}

Tags: align

Good day, I'm trying to box a `case` function while also trying to align it with equations above it. Normally I would use `\Aboxed` but it doesn't seem to work for the `align` environment. `\boxed` doesn't work in the `align` environment. My code looks something like this but it works only if

```
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
```

in the 3rd and 4th lines in the sample code is removed.

```
\subsubsection{$M_{max}$ if A is out of span} %MmaxAout
\begin{align}
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
\Aboxed{M_{max} &=\begin{cases}
\frac{(RL-Bd)^2}{4RL} &\text{if $B<C$,} \\
\frac{(RL-Cd)^2}{4RL} &\text{if $C<B$}
\end{cases}} 
\end{align}
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the `mathtools` manual:

> As `\Aboxed` looks for the alignment `&` it may be necessary to *hide*
>   constructions like matrices that also make use of `&`. Just add a set
>   of braces around the construction you want to hide.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a&=b \\
a&=b \\
\Aboxed{M_\mathrm{max} &={\begin{cases*}
\frac{(RL-Bd)^2}{4RL} & if $B<C$, \\
\frac{(RL-Cd)^2}{4RL} & if $C<B$
\end{cases*}}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Minor improvements:

- the subscript "max" in roman;
- I used the `cases*` environment, which automatically puts the second column in text mode;

Using `dcases*` employs `\displaymath` in the first math column, i.e. it would give bigger fractions.

Comment: Is there a comprehensive documentation that explains the functionalities of Latex and AMSMath? I've found documentations for both but they seem to cover only the most basic.